# How to fix the library of widgets in Xcode 10 as it hides away after selecting one widget ios

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode10

In recent `beta versions of Xcode 10` the widget library has been moved to independent button besides inspector navigation area, when we click on that, it shows the all the widgets like , `ViewControllers, lables, buttons` etc, but when we select any widget the library imidiately hides away and I need to select the button of library to select widgets from libarary. It wastes my time and is a great bad user experience!

Anyone tell me how to make this library fix so i can select multiple widgets but is should not hide away itself?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I was looking the same and then I found a really useful answer:

If you press Option when you drag&drop your object, the window will remain open.

Also you can open the window easily with Shift+Command+L